# Xcode 5 Error ITMS-9000 Invalid Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I've downloaded and checked all of my distribution certificates, as well as provisioning profiles.  I keep getting this error message:

`ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.-----.---- [---.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] .....`

Read that I need to download the distribution com.----.---- provisioning profile but I only have a APPNAME provisioning profile.  Downloaded it anyway and still have the same issues.

I've gone through and downloaded all possible combinations, but still can't get anything to work with application loader.  Everything before has worked fine until I had to upgrade to a new MBP.

Do I revoke anything even though it's valid for another 6 months?

Comment: Have you rebuilt the app? Or you used the old built app for submission (with new provisioning)?

Comment: Old, I guess I'll have to go through and redo the whole thing again.  It just doesn't make any sense as to why it won't read the distribution profiles I downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

AppStore submission has 2 steps:

1. Build archive (via Xcode Archive command)
2. Build ipa for submission (via Organizer / Application Loader)

Each of them require certificate, provisioning and entitlements (in provisioning) for separate (but related) use.

You should use the same provisioning for the two steps. If you can’t find the exact old provisioning, you may consider re-archive the app. I don’t know why Apple splits these steps as they are highly related.

Comment: awesome! just went to ( Product - Archive - ...Distribution ) and it fixed the issue with a few more steps.

Comment: You are welcome ;-) If the answer is correct, please upvote or accept it. This can show to others the answer is correct ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I also have this issue.

It seems to me that the key is to make sure that the "product" you are dealing with has been associated with a DISTRIBUTION provisioning profile that has been signed by the code signing identity which has the right to upload items to the app store (typically a company, or an individual developer).

However, the problem I typically face is that the *.app "product" at the foot of the project navigator list (in the 'products' group) is NOT the output of the archive operation. I can tell this from the time stamp. I do not know where the archive operation places its product. (Perhaps someone here can explain how this works).

As a consequence, what I do is I set ALL the provisioning profiles in the 'Code Signing' section of the 'Build Settings' to the DISTRIBUTION provisioning profile. I then "BUILD for RUN". This results in a *.app file in the 'Products' section of the 'Project Navigator' pane that, while it is the result of a "Build to Run" operation, is properly signed for distribution. I can tell that the *.app product is "fresh" by the time stamp.

It is then this *.app product which I compress and deploy using Application Loader.

This seemed to work - today.

(I confess that I am an amateur and I find the provisioning process somewhat cargo-cult-like, and what I write above may be a kind of infantile superstition about what works.)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. To fix this you must do the following:

When you "click" on Build, please go to:

Product -> Build for -> Profiling

Your file (.app) are created.

To achieve this archive it should do the next step:

XCode -> Preferences ->

Choose the "locations" option, and you will get a screen with different options and routes. Select the route: Derived Data.

You take the app file, and the other file App.dSYM generated in the default folder "release-iphoneos" ... to update these two files in iTunes, you should  compress these two files and upload with "Application loader".

Works fine, good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should also download the certificate from Apple and also put p12 of this certificate (=private exported certificate key) file to your keychain.

Answer (score 0):

## This is my proble to upload my app ..

I try to more then 10 time to upload my app but not accept itune store
then i take this process and after accept my app

[image]

after then i same change as following here
In plist file are show here
[image]

then i take change to here for bundle name is wrong and "test code" space are remove
after then change is
[image]

Then I upload my app in itune and accept itune store
really this is works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just clean all the things.

Check the developer/distribution certificate and mobile provision profile properly created, if not then revoke them from developer account and create all new one.

Remove all profiles from /Users/yourSystemName/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Now, Export all certificates and keys from your keychain and Save them as backup for using them again.

Now install your developer/Distribution certificate first and install provisioning profile. And upload your application. This is tested way and should resolve your issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean your project files - that worked for me after receiving this error.